# Disallow query parameters on certain files in IIS 7.5 or with .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7.5

Is there a generic way to disallow querystring parameters on a for example `.swf` files in IIS 7 or using .Net?

We have an appllication with a thrid party swf file that allows XSS by calling it with certain query string parameters. Therefore we want to disable the parameters in a generic way.

The only thing that comes to my mind is writing a handler that reroutes the file call to a call with no parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an `Handler`, just a new IIS `Rewrite` rule that will match `yourfile.swf?*` and will rewrite it as `yourfile.swf` (explicitly without appending `querystring`).

Something like (didn't check it):

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="strip_querystring" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="yourfile.swf*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="yourfile.swf" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This looks like a nice and clean solution. Is it possible to have it match on all files that have the .swf extension?

Comment: `<rule name="strip_querystring" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*.swf*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>`

Please make sure it does work as i'm not checking those rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the Global.asax BeginRequest event

```
 Private Sub Global_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.BeginRequest

        Dim httpContext As HttpContext = httpContext.Current
        Dim request As HttpRequest = httpContext.Request
        Dim response As HttpResponse = httpContext.Response

        If request.QueryString.Count > 0 AndAlso request.Url.LocalPath.EndsWith(".swf", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) = True Then
            response.Redirect(request.Url.LocalPath)
        End If


    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm terrible at VB but I understand what you are suggesting and had already made a similiar implementation of this in a handler. I'm probably switching to the rewrite rule suggested above since it fits the problem better in my situation.